# Merging similar groups in concatenated PIG input files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a Pig job that runs daily tracking some users accounts where each user has a number of transactions a day. As part of the process this PIG writes out the transactions grouped by user per day (as an aside using Avro).

I now want to group together all of the transactions for a week (or over a longer period) per user account and process.

I can do this by brute force as follows in PIG, but it seems that there must be a better way than flatten and re-group all of the transactions. In more detail ...

Starting point that works ... (a is a user, (b,c) and (d,e) represents two transitions as do (f,g) and (h,i)

I read in ...

```
(a,{(b,c),(d,e)})  -- From first file - Monday
(a,{(f,g),(h,i)})  -- from second file - Tuesday
```

I Want ...

```
(a,{(b,c),(d,e),(f,g),(h,i)})
```

I get close with script …

```
-- Read in multiple days (one day per file, $input is directory with all files)
DayGroupedRecord = LOAD '$input' USING AvroStorage();
FlattenRecord = FOREACH DayGroupedRecord GENERATE $0 AS Key, FLATTEN ($1);
WeeklyGroup = GROUP FlattenRecord BY $0;
```

This gives

```
(a,{(a,b,c),(a,d,e),(a,f,g),(a,h,i)})
```

Which is good enough. However the group has to operate at the per transaction level seems inefficient as input records already part grouped.

Is there a different approach in PIG (perhaps more efficient) where I group the daily groups and then flatten?

I have tried (and failed) with ...

```
DayGroupedRecord = LOAD '$input' USING AvroStorage();
WeeklyGroupNested = GROUP DayGroupedRecord  BY $0;
WeeklyGroup = FOREACH WeeklyGroupNested GENERATE FLATTEN($1);
```

The group operation looks promising …

```
(a,{(a,{(b,c),(d,e)}),(a,{(f,g),(h,i)})})
```

But I can’t find out how to flatten out the inner in the above bag .. the script have have just gets me back to where I started ... I have tried a number of variations on the flatten with no success (mostly generating PIG errors).

This is what I get and with above script (and not what I want).

```
(a,{(b,c),(d,e)})
(a,{(f,g),(h,i)})
```

As a Newbe to PIG can I get pig to flatten the inner bag and get close to what I want:

```
(a,{(b,c),(d,e),(f,g),(h,i)})
```

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "brute force" method and compared the resource consumption with what you get when you, e.g., just `GROUP` and forget about trying to get the transactions into a single bag? You might not find the brute force method elegant, but think about what it's doing and whether there's really much inefficiency in it.

Your ideal way is to group by user and merge all the bags that get grouped together.  This would mean sending for each input record the key and the bag of transactions to some reducer. From there you would have to iterate through the bags, pulling out each transaction and putting it into a final bag for that user.

The brute force method uses `FLATTEN` so that for each transaction in each input record, you send the key and the transaction to some reducer.  There's some duplication here by repeatedly sending the user ID, but this isn't that big of a deal, particularly if the size of your transaction data is much larger than the size of your user ID.  From there, you just add each transaction into a final bag for that user.

That doesn't sound particularly inefficient to me, and it doesn't involve any extra map-reduce steps.  The size of the data sent from the mappers to the reducers is pretty close to the same.  I suspect that you are not going to substantially increase performance by trying to keep the transactions for a day grouped together throughout the computation.